# Wordpress is redirecting 302-307 in loop

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-302, wp-admin, http-status-code-307

I was setting up End-to-end Cloudflare for my VPS running Wordpress.
Having problem accessing wp-admin, loops in redirects.

By perusing google I have tried many things and it lead me to final point where 302 loops with 307. So https is redirecting to http and back to https again and again.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvirp.png)

Can anyone explain how in the this world does wp-admin page redirect itself twice ? Where are the php rules which guide such behavior?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Flexible encryption mode, configure CloudFlare to https only and in wp-config set

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', false);
```